# Update available drop targets after dragstart fires in jquery.event.drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

**Overview:**

I have a page which uses [jquery.event.drag](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag) and [jquery.event.drop](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop).
I need to be able to drag and drop onto elements which are constantly being added to the dom, even after the drag has started.

---

**Problem:**

When the `dragstart` event fires it checks for available drop targets and adds them to the drag object.

The problem I have is I am adding drop targets dynamically, after  the `dragstart` event has fired, and therefore the user cannot drop onto these dynamically added drop targets.

---

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/36AJq/

---

**Question:**

How can I update the drag to allow dropping on elements which have been added to the dom after drag has started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this snippet.

The important function is: `$.event.special.drop.locate();`

Tested on chrome/safari/firefox/ie9 and seems to work.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qtnQF)

---

**UPDATE**

For overlapping events, see if following code works. I set it inside an anonymous function just to avoid any global variable.
Idea is to use currentTarget property of event to check if not the same element is triggering same event. I set an id on newdrop element just in purpose of test here.

[SEE UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qtnQF/4/)

```
(function () {
    var $body = $("body"),
        newdrops = [],
        currentTarget = {},
        ondragstart = function () {

            $(this).css('opacity', .75);
        }, ondrag = function (ev, dd) {
            $(this).css({
                top: dd.offsetY,
                left: dd.offsetX
            });
        }, ondragend = function () {

            $(this).css('opacity', '');
            for (var i = 0, z = newdrops.length; i < z; i++)
            $(newdrops[i]).off('dropstart drop dropend').removeClass('tempdrop');
            newdrops = [];
        }, ondropstart = function (e) {
            if (currentTarget.dropstart === e.currentTarget) return;
            currentTarget.dropstart = e.currentTarget;
            currentTarget.dropend = null;
            console.log('start::' + e.currentTarget.id)
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }, ondrop = function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("dropped");
        }, ondropend = function (e) {
            if (currentTarget.dropend === e.currentTarget) return;
            currentTarget.dropend = e.currentTarget;
            currentTarget.dropstart = null;
            console.log('end::' + e.currentTarget.id)
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        };

    $body.on("dragstart", ".drag", ondragstart)
        .on("drag", ".drag", ondrag)
        .on("dragend", ".drag", ondragend)
        .on("dropstart", ".drop", ondropstart)
        .on("drop", ".drop", ondrop)
        .on("dropend", ".drop", ondropend);



    var cnt = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        var dataDroppables = $body.data('dragdata')['interactions'] ? $body.data('dragdata')['interactions'][0]['droppable'] : [];

        var $newDrop = $('<div class="drop tempdrop" id="' + cnt + '">Drop</div>');
        cnt++;
        $("#dropWrap").append($newDrop);
        var offset = $newDrop.offset();
        var dropdata = {
            active: [],
            anyactive: 0,
            elem: $newDrop[0],
            index: $('.drop').length,
            location: {
                bottom: offset.top + $newDrop.height(),
                elem: $newDrop[0],
                height: $newDrop.height(),
                left: offset.left,
                right: offset.left + $newDrop.width,
                top: offset.top,
                width: $newDrop.width
            },
            related: 0,
            winner: 0
        };
        $newDrop.data('dropdata', dropdata);
        dataDroppables.push($newDrop[0]);
        $newDrop.on("dropstart", ondropstart)
            .on("drop", ondrop)
            .on("dropend", ondropend);
        $.event.special.drop.locate($newDrop[0], dropdata.index);
        newdrops.push($newDrop[0]);
    }, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: Also any idea how you can stop drag events overlapping? See console on http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/qtnQF/2/

Comment: You should be able to stop overlapping playing with tolerance in drop.js. Not sure about that i don't have enough time in hand to play with but seems to be what you are looking for. Other way, simpler way, is to use e.currentTarget of respective events to check if not the same previous element is triggering the event. I'll update my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get this working using jquery.event.drag and jquery.event.drop, but I did make it work with the native HTML5 events:

http://jsfiddle.net/R2B8V/1/

The solution was to bind the events on the drop targets within a function and call that to update the bindings. I suspect you could get this working with jquery.event.drag and jquery.event.drop using a similar principal. If I can get those working I will update my answer.

Here is the JS:

```
$(function() {
    var bind_targets = function() {
        $(".drop").on({
            dragenter: function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                return true;
            },
            dragleave: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            },
            drop: function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("dropped");
            }
        });
    };    

    $("div[draggable]").on({
        dragstart: function(evt) {
            evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', 'data');
        },
        dragend: function(evt) {
            $('.active.drop').removeClass('active');   
        }
    });
  setInterval(function () {
      $("#dropWrap").append('<div class="drop">Drop</div>');
      // Do something here to update the dd.available
      bind_targets();
  }, 1000)
});
```

Comment: This has two problems: browser comparability and customization. (e.g., cursor position and location of `.drag` on `dragEnd`.)

Comment: I didn't say it was a perfect solution. I was illustrating a concept.

Comment: The customization you mentioned can be implemented here. Regarding browser compatibility, this will work in the vast majority of browsers. It won't work in IE 8 or lower, but that's not necessarily a problem.

Comment: It looks like @roasted just posted the solution you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can't. On `dragstart`, possible drop zones are calculated from the DOM, and can't be edited until `dragend`. Even constantly rebinding the `.on()` (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/36AJq/84/) will not provide the desired effect.

I solved the issue a little differently. (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/36AJq/87/)

1. Start with every `<div>` in the HTML.
2. Apply `opacity: 0` to make it invisible, and `width: 0` to keep it from getting a `dropend` when hidden.
3. Use `setInterval` to show the next hidden div (`$('.drop:not(.visible)').first()`) each 1000ms.

JS:

```
$("body")
  .on("dragstart", ".drag", function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', .75);
  })
  .on("drag", ".drag", function (ev, dd) {
    $(this).css({
      top: dd.offsetY,
      left: dd.offsetX
    });
  })
  .on("dragend", ".drag", function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '');
  })
  .on("dropstart", ".drop", function () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  })
  .on("drop", ".drop", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("dropped");
  })
  .on("dropend", ".drop", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
setInterval(function () {
    $('.drop:not(.visible)').first()
      .addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Would the downvoter please let me know why they downvoted my answer?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but since you downvoted me for having a less than perfect solution, I will point out the problem in yours. It requires all the drop targets to be created when the dragging starts, when the most essential part of the question was the need to add drop targets dynamically.

Comment: The elements get dynamically added and removed from the dom for a reason, to keep the dom size down and improve performance, FYI im applying this to a js grid, the amount of rows could range from 1 to 10000, but as im using a grid there will only ever be about 50 on the page at any given time

Answer (score -1):

Enable the [refreshPositions option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-refreshPositions).

Comment: The OP isn't using jQueryUI.

Comment: Also refreshPositions doesnt solve the problem in JQUI http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7619

Answer (score -2):

Why not place all the divs into the page and set their visibility to hidden? Then use setInterval() to change each one's visibility every second.

Comment: The elements get dynamically added and removed from the dom for a reason, to keep the dom size down and improve performance

Comment: @Blowsie What if you set their width/height to 0 and then increased it to the needed size each second.

Comment: they would still be in the dom and slow, then resizing them would cause a reflow. Its really not a viable option